# Upper bounds for $n^{1/p} p$

Tags: functions, optimization, asymptotics, intuition, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find, for given natural $n$, the positive real value for $p$ that minimizes

$$f(n,p) = n^{1/p} p$$

So there is a minimum value, for each natural number $n$, that $f(n,p)$ takes on as $p$ ranges over all positive reals, and we can call this value $g(n)$, since it is really only a function of $n$, because $p$ is pre-determined, given $n$.  I'm looking for to find the best bounds $O(g(n))$.

Answer (score 1):

Partially differentiating $f$ wrt to $p$ gives;

$$\frac{\delta f}{\delta p}=n^{\frac{1}{p}}(1-\frac{1}{p}\ln{n})$$

This is equal to zero for stationary points. This gives either $n=0$ or $n=e^p$.

Similarly Partially differentiating $f$ wrt to $n$ gives;

$$\frac{\delta f}{\delta n}=n^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$$

Which is equal to zero for stationary points. This gives $n=0$.

Now $f(0,p)=0$, hence the stationary points are on the line $n=0$ have value of $0$.

Now $f(e^p,p)=ep$, hence the stationary points are on the line $n=e^p$ have value of $ep$.

Further work using the Hessian is needed to show if points on $n=0$ and $n=e^p$ are minima or maxima.

I am not able to advise on an asymptotic approximation.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well.  We are given $n$, and the idea is to find the value of $p$ that minimizes $n^{1/p}p$.  Then I want to know how the value $n^{1/p}p$ grows with $n$ asymptotically.

Comment: There is an error in your first partial derivative. Instead of $\ln p$ it should be $\ln n$.

Comment: Thank you. Updated answer.

Comment: @downvoter please put rational for the down votes. It is not helpful just down voting without explaining why.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess the down votes come from the fact that it's unclear whether you answer to the question. Why would you take the derivative with respect to $n$? The OP only looks for minima of the function $f(n,\cdot)$ for fixed $n$. And if "further work" is needed to determine whether you have a maximum or a minimum, why not do it? Also, the question about asymptotics is not addressed.

Comment: Ok thanks for your thoughts. Will update answer soon.